# EntityFramework using wrong tablename

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

My code is giving me an EntityCommandExecutionException when i'm trying getting data from my Bieren Table.

The exception message says that it can't find "dbo.Biers" which is quite obvious because it's called "dbo.Bieren".

I can quite easily fix this by just renaming the table in the database. Altough i don't like fixing my database around my code's errors.

How can i make the entity framework use the correct table instead of changing the name of my table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the exception say dbo.Biers or dbo.Bierens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the database-first approach, StriplingWarrior's solution works well. But if you use the code-first approach, you could use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.TableAttribute` on a target entity class to map an entity class to a database table.

However, this way is slightly annoying, because we commonly want to define a pure  entity class. To do this, you could entrust it to another class or use the overrided `OnModelCreating` method in the `DbContext` class as the following.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
        .ToTable("MyCategories");
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Decorate your entity class with the `TableAttribute` property, e.g.

```
[Table("Bieren")]
```

Answer (score 6):

Your Entity Framework model has information about the table names and connections that it is connecting to. If you're using a database-first approach, you should have an EDMX file with your database model in it. The easiest way is to update the model from the database.

1. Open the EDMX file in Visual Studio
2. Delete the incorrect "Biers" table
3. right-click in the background and click "Update Model from database"
4. Point the wizard at your database, and select the "Bieren" table to add
5. Finish the wizard, and the "Bieren" table should appear

It is also possible to dig into the properties of the Biers type, and manually change the table name.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But i'm not using the DataBase first approach. I'm using a variation on code-first where i associate my model classes with an existing database. (I'm a MVC3 and EF4 starter, got that from a book). Is there a way to fix this with the code-first approach?

Comment: @Wesz-T: It looks like jwJung beat me to it. Cheers.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Hi stripling, do you happen to know how I could do this with a table that is only used for relationships (for many-to-many)? It doesn't appear in edmx as a selectable object as other tables do

Comment: @Bassie: It's been awhile since I played with an edmx, but I seem to remember that the relationship itself is selectable (possibly by clicking on the line between the entities, or by clicking on the relationship property).